# how to print individual recipient in mail merge in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have 15 recipients to print the Letters however I want to print individual copies how can I do this without selecting next recipient option (>>).

Answer (score 0):

Under the Finish and Merge Button Select - "Edit Individual Documents" this will create a document for each merged record.